# Jquery .off all handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax

Maybe something relevant that I'm missing but if I use this when document ready

```
$('a.edit').on("click", displayEditForm);
```

And then this after an ajax call

```
$('a.edit').off();
$('a.edit').on('click', displayEditForm);
```

It works, I need to deattach because some of the a.click are dynamically loaded and some aren't so I want to attach only once to all of them. Problem is that this works for now but I would like to use

```
$('a.edit').off('click', displayEditForm);
$('a.edit').on('click', displayEditForm);
```

and that's not working. It doesn't fail but some of them are calling the function twice when clicked. Doesn't work neither if I use

```
$('a.edit').off('click', '**');
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Use event delegation and forget about constantly calling `off` and then `on` again.  Have a look at the event delegation section of the `on` documentation.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why would you like to use the second block if the first block is working?

Comment: Gonna give that a try, I would like to use the second one because the first one is removing all handlers, for the moment I only have that one but maybe in the future there will be more needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are generating them dynamically you can bind the `click()` like these :

```
$(document).on('click' , 'a.edit', function(){})
```

or use `$(document).delegate('a.edit', 'click', function(){})`

Personally I use the first solution

Comment: There's also no reason to mention using `.delegate()` at all if they're using a version containing `.on()` (1.7+).

Comment: Unless they were writing a plugin that they wanted to be backwards compatible, but it's not normal to use event delegation in a plugin anyway.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yeah, I know, in fact I wrote the first solution as the good one. The second as other solution

Comment: Yes, it's not a plugin. Actually I can use it on a lower level (probably not very technical wording) than the document and it works. Thanks